# Auto redirect page to next page without click

Tags: javascript, php

How can I redirect page to next page without click automatically ?
I want to edit my code ( to auto redirect page to next page without click )

```
    <div class="col-md-<?= $col_num ?>">
        <?= $this->Flash->render() ?>

        <?= $this->Form->create(null, ['id' => '']); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->hidden('action', ['value' => 'continue']); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->hidden('page', ['value' => $page + 1]); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->button(__('Click here to continue - Step (1/2)'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary',]); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Go to next page after scrolling down**

Here is some Javascript to redirect to the next page when the user scrolls down and sees the button. Essentially, it will automatically click the button as soon as it is visible, instead of the user needing to click it.

You can update the button classes `btn btn-primary` to something more specific if needed, in case there is more than one button with those classes on the page.

```
<script>
function inViewport (el) {
    var r = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var wHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var wWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    return r.top >= 0 && r.left >= 0 && r.bottom <= wHeight && r.right <= wWidth;
}
var buttonElement = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-primary');
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if (inViewport(buttonElement)) {
        buttonElement.click();
    }
});
</script>
```

**Go to next page immediately**

This will take the user to the next page as soon as the page loads. I'm not sure what the use case is for this, but here it is!

```
<script>
var buttonElement = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-primary');
if (buttonElement) {
    buttonElement.click();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Great Solution but I need redirect to the next page without the user scrolls down

Comment: @aboloza So what do you want? Do you simply want the page to go to the next page as soon as it loads? Or do you want a delay?

Comment: go to the next page as soon as it loads

Comment: I want the page to go to the next page as soon as it loads

Comment: @aboloza I have updated my answer with a solution for you.

Comment: Please help me to make it Go to next page after 10 seconds